# Why can we initialize an array only with an initializer-list

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following example

```
#include <iostream>

int a[][2] = {{1, 4}, {2, 6}};
int b[][3] = a; // error: array initializer must be an initializer list
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d269367cf88e4aa)**

Why can't we initialize an array in any way instead of with an `initializer-list`? I tried to find it in the `N4296::8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]` but it seems there is no anything suitable about it.

Comment: "Why" as in "why was it specified that way" or "where does the standard say it"? For the latter, you are looking for [dcl.init]/p17.

Comment: The error message "array initializer must be an initializer list" is quite misleading. Which compiler says this?

Comment: You should probably tag this C, because that's where this behaviour comes from. Also, what is the purpose of `struct A`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Perhaps click on the link that says "DEMO"?

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, it's a C++ question about a C++ program. It should not be tagged C. Please don't encourage more people to double-tag C and C++!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is sort of backwards, as is the error message. It has *always* been the case that you cannot initialise an array from the name of another array. Initializer lists aren't relevant to that.

> `[C++11: 8.5/16]:` The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
> - If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of `char16_t`, an array of `char32_t`, or an array of `wchar_t`, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.
> - If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.
> - **Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.**
> - *[..]*

Comment: Couldn't you clarify why we can't initialize an array with `()`. The quote you cited doesn't prevent it, I think. As far as I understood if the array initalization doesn't satisfy all the points before the _Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed_, than the program is ill-formed. In the example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55282636e770d54b it satasfies the previous point. What's wrong?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: How does it "satisfy the previous point?" The previous point talks about the initializer being `()`, but your initializer is `new int[2]();`.

Comment: So, what would be an example of the `()` initializer? As far as I know the `A a()` declaration is parsed as a function declaration.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: It's possible in the member initialiser list. `Foo::Foo() : myArray() {};` Also in your previous example of `new int[2]()` you have a valid `()` initialiser right in there. (Note that, as I said before, this doesn't make initialising from the `new int[2]()` _itself_ valid!)